# Python will not read the CSV file at all

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have tried this over and over many times and it still will not work. All that I need to do is to read a csv file, but my program will not do it. I have tried the `pandas.read_csv()` and it just says it does not have that attribute:
[My error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w3uiB.png)

I have also tried importing csv and reading it that way but it refuses to admit that there is a file there:
[My other error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6CvG9.png)

And here is my code for pandas:

```
pd.read_csv('data.csv')
```

And my code for the rest:

```
with open('data.csv') as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.DictReader(csv_file)

    row = next(csv_reader)
    print(row)
```

And last but not least, here is the proof that the file exists: [Proof](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xeKhE.png)

Comment: You probably overwrote the method. Try restarting your environment with fresh python. Then try again.

Comment: Rename your “pandas.py” python file. Your code is trying to look for a function named “read_csv” in that file because it is named pandas.

Comment: Rename your “pandas.py” file. The code is trying to find a function named “read_csv” in this file because it is named pandas.

Comment: Thanks and sorry I am kind of new to this

Comment: One piece of advice: Try to avoid posting links to your error messages in form of screenshots. It's much better to copy them as plain text and post as `code samples` what makes them integral part of your question and is much easier to read.

Answer (score 1):

Do not create modules using library names. Rename pandas.py. Try again.

```
df= pd.read_csv('data.csv')
```